# My article doesn't display in article_details

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to show my articles but
My article doesn't display on article_details.html

This is what my site looks like. You can see only my article's title works.

[image: Articles had to be published there.]

My models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Title")
    mini_description = models.TextField(max_length=100, default='', verbose_name='Mini_description')
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name="Content")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date of add")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Update date")
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', verbose_name="Photo")
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Is published")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Category")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("article_details", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Article(pk={self.pk}, title='{self.title}')"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Article"
        verbose_name_plural = "Articles"
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

My views.py:

```
class ArticleListByCategory(ListView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    template_name = 'blog/details.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        sort_filed = self.request.GET.get('sorter')
        articles = Article.objects.filter(category_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        if sort_filed:
            articles = articles.order_by(sort_filed)

        return articles

class ArticleDetails(ArticleListByCategory):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article'
    template_name = 'blog/article_details.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        article = Article.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'], is_published=True).select_related('category')
        return article

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        article = Article.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['title'] = f"Article: {article.title}"
        return context
```

My article_details.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block style %}
<link href="{% static 'blog/css/main.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock style %}

{% block title %}
{{ title }}
{% endblock %}


{% block main %}

<section class="articles" id="articles">
    <div class="card_details">
        <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
        <p><em>{{ article.mini_description }}
        </em>
        </p>
        <img src="">
        <div class="description">
            <p>
                {{ article.content }}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            {{ article.created_at| timesince }} ago
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

{% endblock main %}
```

I don't know why my article doesn't display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd suggest here is using the `Django Generic View` called `DetailView`. For example, you could do the following:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class ArticleDetails(DetailView):
     context_object_name = 'article'
     template_name = 'blog/article_details.html'

     # Using the get_object method here, not get_queryset.
     def get_object(self, queryset=None):
         article = Article.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'], is_published=True).select_related('category')
         return article
```

Ideally, that should work.